# Converting line breaks into <li> tags

Tags: php, function, textarea, line-breaks

I'm creating an upload form that has a text area for users to input cooking recipes with. Essentially, what I want to do is wrap each line in a `<li>` tag for output purposes. I've been trying to manipulate the `nl2br` function but to no avail. Can anyone help?

I'm retrieving the text area's content via POST and storing entries in a MySQL database. 
Here's what the code looks like at the moment (the `check_input` function strips slashes, etc.):

```
$prepText=check_input($_POST['preparationText']);    
$cookText=check_input($_POST['cookingText']);
```

Comment: Where is your data coming from? How is it stored? etc.. do you want us to guess all that?

Comment: Sorry, I realise I gave you nothing to work from. I'm retrieving the textarea content via POST and storing them in a MySQL database. Here's what the code looks like at the moment (the check_input function strips slashes etc):  $prepText=check_input($_POST['preparationText']);
$cookText=check_input($_POST['cookingText']);

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Explode the string by `\n` then wrap each line in an `li` tag.

```
<?php
$string = "line 1\nline 2\nline3";

$bits = explode("\n", $string);

$newstring = "<ol>";
foreach($bits as $bit)
{
  $newstring .= "<li>" . $bit . "</li>";
}
$newstring .= "</ol>";
```

Answer (score 8):

Not quite pretty, but an idea that comes to mind is to :

- explode the string, using newline as a separator
- and implode the array, using `</li><li>` between items :

Which could be translated to something like this :

```
$new_string = '<li>' . implode('</li><li>', explode("\n", $old_string)) . '</li>';
```

*(Yeah, bad idea -- don't do that, especially if the text is long)*

Another solution, way cleaner, would be to just **replace the newlines in your string by `</li><li>`** :

*(wrapping the resulting string inside `<li>` and `</li>`, to open/close those)*

```
$new_string = '<li>' . str_replace("\n", '</li><li>', $old_string) . '</li>';
```

With that idea, for example, the following portion of code :

```
$old_string = <<<STR
this is
an example
of a 
string
STR;

$new_string = '<li>' . str_replace("\n", '</li><li>', $old_string) . '</li>';
var_dump($new_string);
```

Would get you this kind of output :

```
string '<li>this is</li><li>an example</li><li>of a </li><li>string</li>' (length=64)
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a function based on Richard's answer in case it saves anyone some time!

```
/**
 * @param string $str - String containing line breaks
 * @param string $tag - ul or ol
 * @param string $class - classes to add if required
 */
function nl2list($str, $tag = 'ul', $class = '')
{
    $bits = explode("\n", $str);

    $class_string = $class ? ' class="' . $class . '"' : false;

    $newstring = '<' . $tag . $class_string . '>';

    foreach ($bits as $bit) {
        $newstring .= "<li>" . $bit . "</li>";
    }

    return $newstring . '</' . $tag . '>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
function nl2li($str)
{
    if (!isset($str)) return false;
    $arr = explode("\r\n", $str);
    $li  = array_map(function($s){ return '<li>'.$s.'</li>'; }, $arr);
    return '<ul>'.implode($li).'</ul>';
}
```

Input:

```
Line 1\r\nLine2\r\nLine3\r\n
```

Output:

```html
<ul><li>Line 1</li><li>Line 2</li><li>Line 3</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it:

```
function ln2ul($string) {
  return '<ul><li>' . str_replace("\n", '</li><li>', trim($string)) . '</li></ul>';
}
```